# How and why can fork() fail?

Tags: c, posix

I'm currently studying the fork() function in C. I understand what it does (I think). Why do we check it in the following program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int pid;
  pid=fork();

  if(pid<0) /* Why is this here? */
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed");
    exit(-1);
  }
  else if (pid == 0)
  {
    printf("Printed from the child process\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Printed from the parent process\n");
    wait(pid);
  }
}
```

In this program we check if the PID returned is < 0, which would indicate a failure. Why can fork() fail?

Comment: If for some reason you can't make more processes on your OS, it will fail.  This is just one way though.

Answer (score 25):

From the man page:

```
Fork() will fail and no child process will be created if:
[EAGAIN]           The system-imposed limit on the total number of pro-
                   cesses under execution would be exceeded.  This limit
                   is configuration-dependent.

[EAGAIN]           The system-imposed limit MAXUPRC (<sys/param.h>) on the
                   total number of processes under execution by a single
                   user would be exceeded.

[ENOMEM]           There is insufficient swap space for the new process.
```

(This is from the OS X man page, but the reasons on other systems are similar.)

Answer (score 21):

`fork` can fail because you live in the real world, not some infinitely-recursive mathematical fantasy-land, and thus resources are finite. In particular, `sizeof(pid_t)` is finite, and this puts a hard upper bound of 256^sizeof(pid_t) on the number of times `fork` could possibly succeed (without any of the processes terminating). Aside from that, you also have other resources to worry about like memory.

Comment: "...because you live in the real world, not some infinitely-recursive mathematical fantasy-land, and thus resources are finite." - too good!

Comment: See also `malloc()` - yet it is worrying how often you find code that assumes malloc() returns a valid pointer

Answer (score 2):

There is not enough memory available to make the new process perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

If the kernel fails to allocate memory for example, that's pretty bad and would cause `fork()` to fail.

Have a look at the error codes here:

http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it can fail (not really fail but hang infinitely) due to the following things coming together:

1. trying to profile some code
2. many threads
3. much memory allocation

See also:

- *[clone() syscall infinitely restarts because of SIGPROF signals #97](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/issues/97)*
- *[Hanging in ARCH_FORK with CPUPROFILE #704](https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools/issues/704)*
- *[SIGPROF keeps a large task from ever completing a fork(). Bug 645528](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=645528)*

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    size_t sz = 32*(size_t)(1024*1024*1024);
    char *p = (char*)malloc(sz);
    memset(p, 0, sz);
    fork();
    return 0;
}
```

Build:

```
gcc -pg tmp.c
```

Run:

```
./a.out
```