# Confusion about output of fork calls

Tags: c

Consider the output of the below program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
void main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    int a = 5;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
        printf("This is the son process, a = %d\n", --a);
    else
        printf("This is the dad process, a = %d\n", ++a);
}
```

The output that I expected is:

```
This is the son process, a = 4;
This is the dad process, a = 6;
```

But I got the output as:

```
This is the son process, a = 4
```

So why the parent process did not execute the printf ? How can i get the output i want?

Update:

Just now I tried once more, output like this:

```
$ gcc fork.c -o fork
$ ./fork
This is the dad process, a = 6
$ This is the son process, a = 4
```

Now there is still a problem: why is there a `$` between two lines of output?

I think the expected output should be like this:

```
$ gcc fork.c -o fork
$ ./fork
This is the dad process, a = 6
This is the son process, a = 4
```

I can't figure out why `$` is there.

More details:

```
gcc version: gcc 4.8.2  
OS: ubuntu 14.04
```

Comment: Copy-pasting your code, I get the output you expect. I suggest you specify which OS you're compiling/running this in.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. But you need to `#include <unistd.h>` (instead of pthread.h, pthread.h isn't needed here).  If it still doesn't work, you should post more info, such as how you compile and run your program, and which platform you're working on.

Comment: the printf from son worked but it is the printf from dad which did not work ... you definitely need to specify your environment

Comment: I use the unistd.h instead of pthread.h, but it still doesn't work. This is how I compile: `gcc fork.c -o fork` then `./fork`. My gcc version is 4.8.2 and OS is Ubuntu 14. @nos @theadnangondal @ m0skit0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$` is just the prompt that is displaying in between the process output. Because the child runs "detached" from the parent, the parent may return to the shell before the child has finished. So the prompt is printed, then the child's output. If you would redirect all output to a file, the `$` will not be in there.

Answer (score 4):

You need to check the "fork failed" condition. When fork() returns -1, an error happened. This is part of the semantics of the function, so if you omit it, you will get incorrect results.

See an example which takes into account the possibility of fork failing [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)#Example_in_C).

See a discussion of why fork could fail in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19990704/96780).

Comment: The fork did create a child. Otherwise == 0 check would have failed. It returns 0 only in child and pid of child in parent ... else it returns -1 in parent and child is not created.............. So the child is created it means fork passed

Comment: @theadnangondal He should check -1 before anything else. That's the way it's done. If he omits that check, how can he be sure that everything else is correct? And why omit this check in the first place? It must be there.

Comment: no doubt you are right. But here something happened to parent . child process did it's job